# Question of two functions which are continuous at a certain point

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, continuity, vector-fields

> The electric field $$E_x$$ and its time derivative are continuous at time $t = 0$. Show that $$k = k^,$$
>
> if for $t < 0$
>
> $$E_x = E_0 \cos(kz-wt)$$
>
> and if for $t > 0$
>
> $$E_x = E_1 \cos(k^,z-wt) + E_2 \cos(k^,z-wt).$$

I tried doing this by setting the electric field at $t < 0$ equal to that at $t > 0$ when $t$ is equal to zero and doing the same for the time derivative but I get a whole number of trigonometric functions that will not disappear. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try specifically?

Comment: Although I can't say for sure from the information you've given, it is almost certain that $z$ is a variable and the two relations then have to hold for all $z$. Ergo, you can differentiate the two equations with respect to $z$ (repeatedly) to obtain additional relations.